# how to add new option or update option value of a config file using sed

Tags: shell, sed, sh

i update config file using sed, if the key is not exist, add the key-value, else update the value

```
sed 's/^x=.*/x=z/;t;/\[options\]/ax=z' <<< '[options]'
sed 's/^x=.*/x=z/;t;/\[options\]/ax=z' <<< '[options]
x=y'
```

expect same output:

```
[options]
x=z
```

but the last command output:

```
[options]
x=z
x=z
```

cuz sed process the file line by line, how to make it work properly pls?
?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` isn't the right tool for the job. Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::INI::Reader;
use Config::INI::Writer;

my $file = shift;

my $config = 'Config::INI::Reader'->read_file($file);
$config->{options}{x} = 'z';

rename $file, "$file~";
'Config::INI::Writer'->write_file($config, $file);
```

See [Config::INI](http://p3rl.org/Config::INI) for details on how to process INI files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your command is, your first sed substitution replaces `x=z` with `x=y` and then appends `x=z` after `[options]`.

To obtain the desired output, you need to reverse the order. So

```
sed 's/\[options\]/x=z/;t;/^x=.*/ax=z' <<< '[options]
x=y'`
```

will give you the desired output